# Unexpected results using ST_ClosestPoint: order of arguments make no difference on non-intersecting objects

Tags: postgis, distance

(Note, this is a revision of the original question. I removed distracting information, without changing the original intent of the question)

In this query:

```
select  ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(line, point)) as cp1,
        ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(point, line)) as cp2,
        ST_AsText(point)
    from
        (select ST_Transform(way,4326) as line
            from planet_osm_line where osm_id=8699583) as a,
        (select long_lat_original as point 
            from bicycle_data where id=27) as b;
```

The three returned value (e.g. cp1, cp2, point) are identical; that is, they all have the value of **point**.

I am perplexed that the returned values from ST_ClosestPoint do not seem to depend on the order of the arguments. I feel like I must have missed something obvious.

Comment: If the point is on the line, then the order doesn't matter and the closest point will be the point itself. Now I believe you are not showing the exact query: by using points in 4326, the distance/length of the linestring you have provided is about 2.9e-5 **degrees**, not 2.5 **meters**. I suspect you are casting to geography somewhere, and it is then possible that the point is not on the line anymore due to straight lines in 4326 vs great circle arcs in geography.

Answer (score 1):

JGH, thanks, your comment set me on the path to the following patch...

If I change the 'from' clause in the above query, to be the following:

```
from
        (select ST_Transform(way,4326) as line
            from planet_osm_line where osm_id=8699583) as a,
        (select long_lat_original::geometry as point 
            from bicycle_data where id=27) as b;
```

(note the addition of **::geometry** for **point**) then I get the results I expected; that is the first two values differ with the second value being the same as the value of **point** (the third value). This hack fix lead me to the fact that **long_lat_original** is not in the **geometry_columns** tables (being a GPS point, I assigned it a SRID of 4326, but did not realize that, in my case, it needed to be identified as a geometry item); I believe this falls into the category of 'something obvious' in the question above. New-bee lesson! Hope I got it right. Left the question/answer in place, in case someone else hits the same snag.

Comment: Just a downstream note: the entire problem was fixed when I changed the original definition of the long_lat_original column to geometry(POINT,4326).